# Java hashtable with separate chaining collision resolution?

Tags: java, hashtable, collision

I have created a program using the built in java.util.hashtable but now I need to resolve collisions using separate chaining.  Is it possible with this implementation of a hashtable?  Is there one out there already implemented that uses separate chaining?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [source](http://www.javakey.net/source/jdk/1.6/java/util/Hashtable.java.html) of the Hashtable implementation, it looks like it already uses separate chaining. If you look at the `Entry<K,V>` class starting at line 901, you'll see that it has a reference to another Entry named `next`. If you then look at the `put()` method, on line 420 the `next` reference is populated via the constructor to be whatever element was previously stored in that bucket.

Note that you shouldn't generally be concerned about implementation details such as these. The Java Collections Framework is probably one of the most widely used frameworks in Java, and as such you should assume that the authors have tuned the performance to be as good as it's going to get.

One other thing I'd like to point out is that the Hashtable class has been mostly replaced by the [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class (which also uses separate chaining, see [here](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)). The main difference between the two is that all of the methods in `Hashtable` are synchronized, whereas in `HashMap` they are not. This leads to better performance in situations where you are running in a single threaded environment (possibly the reason for this question?).

If you *do* need a thread-safe map implementation, then you should consider either wrapping a normal `HashMap` in a call to [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)), or using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).