# Hashmap with separate chaining

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

Is there an implementation of the java Map interface which utilizes separate chaining as collision resolution. By reading the javadocs for HashMap and HashTable I came to the conclusion that what the implementation does is basically replace the value and essentially doesn't employ any collision resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756479/java-hashtable-with-seperate-chaining-collision-resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it wrong: it uses a linked list of entries for each bucket.

When putting a value in the map, the map starts by calling `hashCode` on the key, then transforms this hash code so that it's between 0 and the number of buckets. If the bucket is empty, the key is stored in this bucket. If it's not, then every key in this bucket is compared to the new key with `equals`. If one is equal, then its value is replaced by the new value. Else, a new entry with the new key is added to the bucket's list of entries.

If you want to store multiple values for a given key, then use a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, or use Guava's [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: Taking a look at the source - yes it uses a Linked List. But it's worth noting that there's a TREEIFY_THRESHOLD, and if that is exceeded for the bucket, then the linked list gets converted into a red-black tree.

Answer (score 3):

It does have collision resolution, but that's because two different keys could plausibly end up in the same bucket after hashing.

If you want to store more than one value for a single key, you can always use `HashMap<KeyType, ArrayList<ValueType>>` and do some housekeeping to initialize the array when necessary.

Comment: Check out Guava's ListMultimap. It implements a `Map<K, List<V>>`: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. I'll keep it in mind for my next project(s).